# Way to express prime factors of a number

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes, symbolic-math, prime-factoring

My task is to return the prime factors of an integer(n).
My question is how do I express this in a mathematical expression for coding?
I know that primes are numbers that are only divisible by 1 and itself but do not know how to put that in code.

I did however find this coding which works but I do not know why:

```
def primes(n):

    primfac = []
    d = 2
    while d*d <= n:
        while (n % d) == 0:
            primfac.append(d)  
            n //= d
        d += 1
    if n > 1:
       primfac.append(n)
    return primfac
```

Can someone explain to me why this coding works? Why is `d` chosen as 2 to start off instead of 1? Also why does he square `d` and check if it's equal to or less than n? and so on.

Comment: `1` is not a prime number.

Comment: It's just trying all numbers, starting with 2, removing the factors as it find them (and appending them to the list).  They will always be prime, because before trying any composite number, its factors will already have been removed from your number.

Comment: Oh, and starting it at 1 makes no sense.  Not only is one not prime, but you'd just end up with an infinite list of 1s as factors.  Think about it.

Comment: still don't understand why the code is appending d, and why d is being squared and checked if its equal to or less than n. Also confused about the n//=d part.

Comment: Briefly, this code starts with d = 2, which is the first prime number, and note that if d is divided by n and d is prime then $d \leq \sqrt{n}$. After checking that d is divided by n, this code reduces n to new number by dividing n by d until d is not divided by the new number.

Comment: "Express in a mathematical expression for coding"? Is this a question about programming? =)  This question is a lot more about algorithms and mathematics than the usual SO question. You might have better luck with other resources, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Factoring_algorithms

Comment: to answer your first question, `[d | d<-[2..x], rem x d==0, isPrime d]` (this one in Haskell but Python's is similar); though as an *algorithm*, your code is much *much* more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`d` Starts off at 2 because you would end up with an infinite list of 1s as factors as [Tom Karzes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5460719/tom-karzes) mentions. The reason he squares `d` and checks if it is equal to `n` is because  you only need to check up to the square root of the number for its factors and `math.sqrt()` is more computationally expensive than squaring as number. What it does is it checks if `d` us a factor of `n` until `d` reaches the square root of `n`. He then appends `d` because it has been checked to be a factor.

Is there anything else you don't understand about the code?

Comment: I wanted to put this in the comments as I don't think this deserves to be a full on answer, but I don't have enough reputation... :D Sorry, this is my second answer on SO :)

Comment: this answered everything about the code, thanks! Last question though, is this the only way to express/check for prime factors? This is an assignment and although I understand how the code works now, I am hesitant on  just copy this coding if there are numerous other ways to do it.

Comment: There are some more sophisticated algorithms that deal with prime factorization and chekcing whether or not numbers are prime, etc. To my knowledge though, this is the fastest way to get the complete list of prime factors of `n`. These algorithms are called [primality tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) but they only check if a number is prime or not. You might be able to change one or two to list the prime factors of `n`, but again, to my knowledge, this is the simplest, and most efficient way of getting the prime factors of `n`.

Comment: You can also optimize this code with the fact that 2 is the only even prime number.  So you start with d=2, you then continue with d=3. Afterwards, you only have to test other odd numbers (5,7,9,11,...).  You do that by increasing d by two instead of by one.